# How would I write another line in a text document with python

Tags: python, text, newline, edit, document

https://pastebin.com/iuw39F3x

This is what I'm working with. On line 43 you can see I'm writing a string to a text file. Once the script looks again I want it to write another string to the text file on another line. How would I do this?

Comment: Please post actual code in the question

Comment: Sorry. I will do that when I ask another question.

Comment: No, please [edit] your current question

Comment: Maybe you need to open the file in append mode, using `"a"` while opening the file to append the contents at the end of file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you append to a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file)

Comment: Anyway, this code will eventually crash with Stack limit exceeded... Learn about `while True` instead of calling `main()` inside of itself

Answer (score 0):

You open the file,  add the text and add the new line char...

Finally close the file too (you don't want to try to open a file that is already open :) )

```
x = open("myfile.txt","a")
x.write("the line here" + '\n')
x.close()
```

In your case

```
file = open("text.txt","a")
file.write(save + '\n')    #here add the new line
file.close()
time.sleep(25)
```